# .htaccess dynamic clean URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been looking for a long time, how to make clean URLs, but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

This is my PHP setup in `index.php`:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET["page"];

    if(file_exists("pages/{$page}.php")) {
        include ("pages/{$page}.php");
    } else if (empty($page)) {
        include ("pages/Home.php");
    } else {
        echo "This page do not exist";
    }
?>
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="Home">Home</a> <!-- Regular navigation link for: Home, About, Contact -->
    </li><li>
        <a href="Project/2">Project</a> <!-- The link I press to see a project -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2

Options -Indexes
```

it perfectly rewrites my URL 
**FROM:** 
    `domain.com/index.php?page=Home.php`
**TO:**
    `domain.com/Home`.

The two Rewrite Rules work perfectly separated, but not together. How can I make these two work with each other?

Comment: Try changing the order of your rules. Rules are processed from top to the bottom, and this rule: `(.*)` matches everything, and that's why the second rule doesn't have to be checked at all.

Comment: i think once its rewritten the GET variable isn't there, and you should get it from the 'REQUEST_URI' instead

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1

Options -Indexes
```

And one more thing, you should use `$_GET` instead of `_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess is destroying the $_GET values, try this instead:

```
<?php

# From the URI, get whatever is after the last slash:
$subject = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pattern = '/.*\/(.*)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
$page = $matches[1];

if(file_exists("pages/{$page}.php")) {
    include ("pages/{$page}.php");
} else if (empty($page)) {
    include ("pages/Home.php");
} else {
    echo "This page do not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems to have worked, but now it keeps adding project to the URL. Every time I press Project/2 (the link for the project page with the project id) it add project to it for example: click project/2: URL (domain.com/project/2), click on Home (domain.com/project/Home). Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I think you just need a slash in front of Home, like this `<a href="/Home">` otherwise it's a relative link and will stay in the project folder